# putc() blocks when sending data across a pipe opened with popen

Tags: c, pipe

First I have following macro

```
#define MSG_UPDATE_DATA 70
```

Then open a pipe with `popen`

```
SensServer = popen("./SensServer", "w") ;
```

In the following code that uses the `putc(...)` function to write to pipe, the function makes the program block and the lines of code following do not execute

```
void requestTempAndPress(int pid) {
    printf("Temp and presure requested. msg_type: %d\n", MSG_UPDATE_DATA);
    int n = putc(MSG_UPDATE_DATA, SensServer);

    printf("Data sent: %d\n", MSG_UPDATE_DATA);
}
```

It outputs `Temp and presure requested. msg_type: 70` fine. But not the "Data sent..." line.

Comment: What is `SensServer`?

Comment: Can you also specify in the question description that how you opened the pipe. Because if you have opened the pipe using popen then please check that you are providing the write flag to it because pipes are unidirectional.

Comment: Can you please provide a ___[MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)___?

Comment: `#define MSG_UPDATE_DATA` or `#define MSG_UPDATE_DATA 70`?

Comment: Unfortunately no, Internet on my laptop has gone haywire

Comment: I can say though it's not a problem to do with the macro, I tried 't' and same problem.

Comment: Whoops yes there should be a 70 on there, I typed it all on my phone

Comment: Okay I think I've figured the cause, it's because I'm forking the process and it's losing the pointer.

Answer (score 0):

As per the man page,

- [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) is a `fd`, type `int`.
- [`putc()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/putc) needs a `FILE* stream` as  argument.

So, most possibly, in your code, you are supplying the wrong type of argument to `putc()`, creating the issue.

Comment: Indeed: `FILE * SensServer, * SoundServer;` and furthermore `SensServer = popen("./SensServer", "w");`

Comment: @HedgepigMatt `pipe()` returns `int`, not `FILE *`. What are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Send data to the SensServer program

Comment: @HedgepigMatt That part is understood, but what I'm trying to ask is why you're calling a `FILE *` _stream_ as `pipe`?

Comment: @HedgepigMatt ok, what is the definiion of `MSG_UPDATE_DATA`? is it a variable or MACRO define?

Comment: That is a macro is defined as 70

Answer (score 0):

Given the information (and lack of a sample program), this sounds like a question asking how to make pipes non-blocking. This has been discussed before, usually for nonblocking *reads*, e.g.,

- [Non-blocking pipe using popen?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1735781/non-blocking-pipe-using-popen)
- [Correct Code - Non-blocking pipe with popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10962044/correct-code-non-blocking-pipe-with-popen) (C++)

The first link mentions [fcntl](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fcntl) and the `O_NONBLOCK` flag which the manual page says can be applied to both reads and writes.

However, using [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen) makes the pipe using buffered I/O, while the operations addressed by `fcntl` are non-buffered `read` and [`write`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/write) (you really cannot mix the two).  If the program were changed to use the low-level [`pipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) (as in the example for the first link), and consistently used the non-buffered I/O, it would give the intended behavior.

Here are links to more general discussion on the topic:

- [Introduction to non-blocking I/O](http://www.kegel.com/dkftpbench/nonblocking.html)
- [Blocking and Non-Blocking I/0](http://www.linux-mag.com/id/308/)

On the other hand (noting comments), if the program fragment is for example part of some larger system doing [*handshaking*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1220499/how-is-a-handshake-generally-implemented-with-regards-to-named-pipes) (expecting a timely response back from the server), that will run into problems.  The fragment is writing a single character across the pipe.  However, `popen` opens a (block-)*buffered* stream. Nothing will be sent directly to the server as single-character writes unless some help is provided.  For instance, one could flush the output stream after each `putc`, e.g.,

```
fflush(SensServer);
```

Alternatively, one could make the stream *unbuffered* by changing it *immediately* after the successful call to `popen`, e.g., using [setvbuf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/setvbuf):

```
setvbuf(SensServer, NULL, _IONBF, 0);
```

Here are links for further reading about buffering in pipes:

- [Turn off buffering in pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25372/turn-off-buffering-in-pipe)
- [Unix buffering delays output to stdout, ruins your day](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/unix-buffering)
- [Force line-buffering of stdout when piping to tee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11337041/force-line-buffering-of-stdout-when-piping-to-tee)

Comment: Just a side note: We were dealing with a process that didn't flush to stdout or print newline at all, so we piped the process to [stdbuf(1)](http://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) and read from it, to see if we have a problem with buffering (we did have a problem with buffering :) )

Answer (score 0):

The problem was due to the fact I initialised the variable SensServer in the parent process but not the child. Which meant the pointer was 0 or I guess a random memory location.

Comment: In many implementations, you would get a core dump.  Is your application working as expected now?